# How to find magnetic materials in terms of magnetic point groups?

Tags: magnetism, symmetry, anti-ferromagnetic

Are there any methods to find materials in terms of the assigned magnetic point group?

For example, I know the magnetic point groups $6'mm'$ and $6'22'$, and I want to find the corresponding antiferromagnetic materials. How can I do this?

Comment: +1 Did you figure out an answer to this yet? Feel free to write a self-answer if you figured it out during the last few months!

Comment: Later I will update all the questions that I posted.

Comment: Hi Jack, were you planning on updating this question?

Comment: @NikeDattani Sorry for the late post.

Comment: Thanks! I gave my +1.

Comment: @NikeDattani You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I figured out how to arrive at that. The way I found is using the [MAGNDATA database](http://webbdcrista1.ehu.es/magndata/index.php?adser=1&ord=id&ord_mode=asc&0px=0px&1p0px=1p0px&1px=1px&2px=2px&3px=3px&1p1px=1p1px).

Just by choosing the *parent space group*, for example, *hexagonal*, you can obtain many structures, listed in a table. At the last line of that table, you can find the corresponding MPG, for example, $6'mm'$. Note that there are many choices you can pick rather than the *parent space group* to narrow the content of the table.